# Taskbar and Tray on Lubuntu gone missing but not on guest account

Tags: lubuntu, taskbar, openbox, system-tray

I'm using Lubuntu 13.04, and something strange happened.

I rebooted after installing some updates, and now when I choose "Lubuntu" on the login screen, I get something similar to "OpenBox"--no taskbar/tray--just a right-click context menu for handling tasks.

Right now I am posting this using "Lubuntu (Netbook)".

How can I get my taskbar and tray back???

Does it have something to do with openbox configuration?

Thanks for your replies ahead of time! :)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried restarting lxpanel from the terminal that is available to launch from the openbox menu?

```
lxpanelctl restart
```

or

```
killall lxpanel && lxpanel --profile Lubuntu
```

source:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/FAQ/Guides#Restart_lxpanel

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and remove the config files by typing:

```
rm -r ~/.config/lxpanel
```

then restart lxpanelctl:

```
lxpanelctl restart
```

Hope it works for you :)